# How can I swap option values of two HTML <select> elements?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to swap two select-option values in my currency converter. I have link icon which activates swapOptions function which swaps two values. This part works fine. The question is how to set this new values to "select" element?

This is my typescript function and I can see in console new values which should be set in select option:

```
startSwap:any;
endSwap: any;
swapOptions(firstOption: any, secondOption: any){

for(let i = 0; i < this.parsedJson.length; i++){
  if(firstOption == this.parsedJson[i].Srednji){
    this.endSwap = this.parsedJson[i].SelectOption;
  }
  else if(secondOption == this.parsedJson[i].Srednji){
    this.startSwap = this.parsedJson[i].SelectOption;
  }
}
console.log("New start option : "+this.startSwap)
console.log("New end option : "+this.endSwap)
}
```

This is my html. I have tried with [(ngModel)] but on change i get empty select elements.

```
  <select name="options" #firstSelect id="slc" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="startSwap">
      <option *ngFor="let a of parsedJson;" class="form-control" (click)="firstSelectValues(a.Jedinica, a.Valuta)" (click)="intervalCurrencyStats()" [(value)]="a.Srednji">{{a.SelectOption}}</option>
    </select>
    <p id="p">End value:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#converter" style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="swapOptions(firstSelect.value, secondSelect.value)" ><i class="fa fa-arrows-v"></i></a></p>
    <select name="options2" #secondSelect id="slc" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="endSwap">
      <option *ngFor="let a of parsedJson;" class="form-control" (click)="secondSelectValues(a.Jedinica, a.Valuta)" [(value)]="a.Srednji">{{a.SelectOption}}</option>
    </select>
```

On this picture you can see two select option elements and the blue arrow which is link to swapOption function. The empty fields are result of clicking the arrow.

[image]

Any advice is welcome. Thanks in advance!

Angular CLI: 9.1.8
Node: 12.13.0

Comment: Try with: swapOptions() { const cloned = Object.assign({},  this.startSwap); this.startSwap = this.endSwap; this.endSwap = cloned; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I have figured this one out.
Now using formGroup and form control

```
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormsModule, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
```

Some changes in HTML:

```
  <form [formGroup]="crForm">
    <select name="options"  #firstSelect id="slc" class="form-control" formControlName="crControl">
      ...
    </select>
    <select name="options2" #secondSelect id="slc" class="form-control" formControlName="crEndControl">
      ...
    </select>
  </form>
```

And in typescript added **private fb: FormBuilder** in constructor, and formbuilder group for setting new values in select-option (also added inside onInit() with hardcoded default values):

```
this.crForm = this.fb.group({
  crControl: [this.startSwap],
  crEndControl: [this.endSwap]
})
```